# How to update the value of array object property with another filed value of the same array object in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In the below restaurant object, I would like to update the `addons` property of the `optionalAddons` object with the value of `addableIngredients`. How can I do so for each restaurant and each item?

```
  "name": "4Cheeze",
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Chicken Grill",
      "addableIngredients": "cheese - 2, mayo - 0",
      "optionalAddons": {
        "addable": 10,
        "addons": ''
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Fried Momo",
      "addableIngredients": "cheese - 2, mayo - 0",
      "optionalAddons": {
        "addable": 10,
        "addons": ''
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

Here is the Mongo playground link to play with: https://mongoplayground.net/p/JVjV2AiocHD

Comment: You may prefer to trim out other fields that are not related with the question. You can also prepare a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @FatihErsoy, thanks I have trimmed the object now. I am not sure how to provide a minimal reproducible example though?

Comment: Do you want to add this value into the array? Do you want to replace the array with this value? Can the array be filled with some values already?

Comment: @AlaminShaikh from minimal reproducible example you can probably give the output format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use an update with a pipeline to push the current value of  `addableIngredients` into the existing array:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {$set: {items: {$map: {
          input: "$items",
          in: {$mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {optionalAddons: {addons: {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$this.optionalAddons",
                      {addons: {$concatArrays: [
                            "$$this.optionalAddons.addons",
                            ["$$this.addableIngredients"]
                       ]}}
                    ]
              }}}
          ]}
  }}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zdEvazdV2PP)

Comment: Thanks! How would you do it if the ```addons``` is a string instead of an array? 

Sorry I mistyped the data and corrected it now.

Comment: This is even simpler: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zGQmFYL_HA7

Comment: Awesome! It works! Can I remove the property ```addableIngredients``` in the same aggregation? If yes, how can I do so?

Comment: by literally mark the wanted field: https://mongoplayground.net/p/-lAmNNa0Ahr

Comment: I removed the ```addableIngredients``` properties this way: https://mongoplayground.net/p/vuxtTew8fbi. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Yes. Looks better